# Where can I find the story? A traffic jam is so large the government eventually dumps concrete over it to make new road

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

About December, 1978 I read a story in a Science or Science Fiction magazine.  While finishing a new highway, the workers discovered a hand sticking out of the concrete holding a diary.  The story was the diary.

A traffic jam was really bad.  To keep people from walking away and abandoning their vehicles, the government quickly installed containment walls.  The military would drop food and water.  Eventually, they dropped suicide pills and started dropping cement from helicopters to cover this huge traffic jam.  The writer of the diary kept writing even while standing on a car with cement past their waist since they we NOT going to commit suicide.

---

It is not [*La autopista del sur*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/261527/story-about-a-traffic-jam-that-lasts-many-days).

Comment: You can read the story here: http://www.williamflew.com/omni6b.html

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is [The Great Moveway Jam](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?64089) by John Keefauver. You presumably read it in the March, 1979 edition of Omni.

After being stuck in a three-month-long traffic jam, the survivors set off on foot, only to learn that the government have decided to resolve the situation by concreting them in.

> I just saw a man who was on a car some 100 yards from me disappear. A load of cement hit him squarely.
> And another just toppled over.  Suicide?
> Here comes a load. (Editor’s note: This sentence was scrawled out so badly it is assumed Littlefinger wrote it as he was actually ducking. Spots of cement were found on this page.).
> It hit about 100 feet from me. Cement is now at my waist. I must raise my hands to write.

Comment: Coincidentally (or not) there was a 1980 made for TV comedy movie called [The Great American Traffic Jam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Great_American_Traffic_Jam), which according to wikipedia was supposedly inspired by the writers being stuck in an LA traffic jam.   That movie has a helicopter aspect of flying in porta-pottys

Comment: @Marshall - [You're very welcome indeed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3iYzyDQ3hQ)